# Segmentation Fault in the pre-defined element g_int_hash

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable, glib

I am using GHashTable in my program to store strings from the files that the user inputs. 
No error is coming except a Segmentation fault in the line

`GHashTable* HT = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);`

I have never seen a segmentation fault in a pre-defined element g_int_hash
Error: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003f2ec74b70 in g_int_hash () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0

My main file

```
#include <cmdheader.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        int status = FAILURE;
        int i; //loop-counter
        char** safe_pointer = NULL;

        printf("before HashTable");
        GHashTable* HT = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);

        if(argc < 2)
        {
                printf("\n <USAGE> : <Program_name> <file1> <file2> ...");
                return FAILURE;
        }
        // program needs to be scalable, all files should be read using variable arguments

        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
                safe_pointer = &argv[i];
                status = read_CMD(safe_pointer, &HT);
                if(status == FAILURE)
                {
                        FILE_READ_ERROR; 
                }
        }
        status = write_CMD();
        if(status == FAILURE)
        {
                FILE_WRITE_ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
}
```

My header_file

```
/************************************************************************************************************   
*   File Name   :   cmdheader.h
*
*   Description :   cmdheader.h contains all necessary headerfiles and macros 
*
* *********************************************************************************************************/

#ifndef __CMD_HEADER_H_
#define __CMD_HEADER_H_

/***********************************************************************************************************
 *                                      HEADER FILES 
 **********************************************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glib.h>

/***********************************************************************************************************
 *                                         MACROS 
 **********************************************************************************************************/

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE 1
#define LINE_LEN 80
#define DELIMS 3

#define FILE_READ_ERROR printf("\n CANNOT READ THE FILE")
#define FILE_WRITE_ERROR printf("\n CANNOT WRITE TO THE FILE")

#endif
```

My functions file

```
#include <cmdheader.h>

int read_CMD(char** save_pointer, GHashTable** Hash);
int write_CMD();

int read_CMD(char** save_pointer, GHashTable **Hash)
{

        GHashTable *HT = *Hash;
        char buffer[LINE_LEN];
        memset(buffer, '\0', LINE_LEN);

        char* save_pointer_new = *save_pointer;
        int key = 1;
        int* key_pointer = &key;
        int parse_errors = 0;
        int parse_error_check = 1;
        char* token = NULL;

        const char delim[DELIMS] = {',', ':', ';'}; 
        FILE* read_file_pointer;
        read_file_pointer = fopen(save_pointer_new, "r");


        while(NULL != fgets(buffer, LINE_LEN, read_file_pointer))
        {
                // check for parse error
                token = strtok(buffer,delim);
                while(NULL != token)
                {
                        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
                        parse_error_check++;
                }

                // parse_error_check checks number of tokens in a command
                // 2 tokens is error, from 4, it is a valid command
                if(parse_error_check != 2 && 
                                ((parse_error_check % 2) ==0))
                {
                        g_hash_table_insert(HT,key_pointer, buffer);
                        key++;
                }

                else
                {
                        parse_errors++;
                }
        }

        printf("\n Element at key : 1 ", g_hash_table_lookup(HT,(gconstpointer)1));
        printf("\n Parse error count : %d", parse_errors);
        return SUCCESS;



}

int write_CMD()
{

        return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using valgrind or a debugger like gdb? are you sure you are linking with the right library?

Comment: random idea try `GHashTable* HT = g_hash_table_new(&g_int_hash, &g_int_equal);`

Comment: @bruceg yes, infact, the segmentation fault is spotted by the gdb itself

Comment: Fyi, as you're using it, both the keys *and* the values stored in your hash table should be independently memory managed from all other keys and values. You're storing the *same* address for each key, and the same address for each value. As you change the values stored at those addresses, the data in the table is corrupted. In short, you're violating the requirements of the pointer abstraction the GHashTable modus operandi mandates.